# Don't know how to use OnCollisionEnter in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have problems with my method OnCollisionEnter, I don't know why it isn't working properly.

Here is my code:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){

    if (col.gameObject.name == "Bullet" && !bulletEnter)
    {
        Debug.Log(enemyLives);
        enemyLives = enemyLives - 1;

        if (enemyLives == 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            //Modificamos el GameManager e incrementamos el dinero que poseemos tras la muerte de Enemy.
            GameManager.Manager.currentGold(enemyGold);
        }

        bulletEnter = true;


    }
    else if (col.gameObject.name == "OtherBullet" && !bulletEnter) {
        enemyLives = enemyLives - 2;
        if (enemyLives == 0)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            GameManager.Manager.currentGold(enemyGold);
        }

        bulletEnter = true;

    }
}

//Cuando sale la colision lo ponemos a false, esto lo realizamos para que unicamente exista un choque con los coliders.
void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
{
    bulletEnter = false;
}
```

As you can see there, when the Bullet reaches Enemy the trigger should be activated but it isn't working, I am using "Debug.Log" for checking if it enters inside the methods but it doesn't.

Here I also add the picture from my inspector.

[image]

Comment: What is the name of this script you posted in your question and where is it attached to?

Comment: Its named Enemy.cs and Its attached to the Prefab called "Enemy".

Comment: Ok. Put `Debug.Log("test");` outside the `if` statement but inside `OnCollisionEnter` and let me know if there is a log.

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesnt work, the logs it shows are from other proves I have done, but the one you said isn't working.  I add here you a photo, http://i63.tinypic.com/14bq4hc.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple scene for this and quickly found your problem. Uncheck **Is Trigger** property on `Box Collider` of your Enemy GameObject. `OnCollisionEnter` should now be called as expected.

Few other improvement on your code:

**1**.Use `CompareTag` instead of checking it by name. Simply change `if (col.gameObject.name == "Bullet" && !bulletEnter)` to  `if (col.transform.CompareTag("Bullet") && !bulletEnter)`.

**2**.Also, you had

```
void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
{
    bulletEnter = false;
}
```

This is not a good logic because anything that collides with the **Enemy** will be considered as a **Bullet**. Check if it is a **Bullet** like you did inside the `OnCollisionEnter` function before setting `bulletEnter` to `false`. This will likely prevent other problems in the future.

Comment: Or change the code to `OnTriggerEnter` depending on the desired behaviour.

Comment: @GunnarB. Yeah he could do that. It depends on what he's doing.